# PC keyboard not working in Android emulator

Tags: android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm unable to use my PC keyboard to input characters into the app running on AVD emulator even though I had chosen 'Enable keyboard input' when creating the AVD. Can anyone help?

Below is my config.ini.

**Note**

> File directory can be accessed from AVD Manager:
>
> -> click the down arrow on the Actions column
>
> -> Show on Disk.
>
> For GNU/Linux users, with default Android Studio configuration, the
>   file is found under directory
>   `/home/<<user>>/.android/avd/<<device>>.avd`

**config.ini**

```
avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
AvdId=Nexus_5_API_21
abi.type=x86_64
avd.ini.displayname=Nexus 5 API 21
disk.dataPartition.size=200M
hw.accelerometer=yes
hw.audioInput=yes
hw.battery=yes
hw.camera.back=none
hw.camera.front=none
hw.cpu.arch=x86_64
hw.dPad=no
hw.device.hash2=MD5:2fa0e16c8cceb7d385183284107c0c88
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
hw.device.name=Nexus 5
hw.gps=yes
hw.gpu.enabled=yes
hw.keyboard=yes
hw.lcd.density=480
hw.mainKeys=no
hw.ramSize=1536
hw.sdCard=yes
hw.sensors.orientation=yes
hw.sensors.proximity=yes
hw.trackBall=no

image.sysdir.1=system-images/android-21/default/x86_64/
runtime.network.latency=none
runtime.network.speed=full
runtime.scalefactor=0.25
sdcard.path=/Users/xxxxxx/.android/avd/Nexus_5_API_21.avd/sdcard.img
skin.dynamic=yes
skin.name=nexus_5
skin.path=/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/nexus_5
snapshot.present=no
tag.display=Default
tag.id=default
vm.heapSize=64
```

More info:
I'm using Mac OS X 10.10.4 (Yosemite). 
Android Studio 1.3

Comment: A later version of this question is at https://stackoverflow.com/q/39993352/120398

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37094173#comment11 describes how to set up a shortcut that manually changes the focus

Answer (score 8):

I had this issue despite having the correct configuration, and realized that the actual problem was that the focus was on the emulator control buttons windows, as reported in [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=207014).

To check if this is your problem, see if pressing space actually presses one of those buttons, and if pressing tab moves the highlight focus square between elements in the emulator controls. If that is the problem, then you should be able to work around it as follows:

- Select the extended controls (The "..." button in the emulator controls)
- Change to any item in the extended controls window by clicking
- Close the extended controls window

The focus should now return to the main Android emulator window, not the emulator controls, and key presses should go to Android apps.

Comment: This worked for me as well, what an annoying and obscure problem.

Comment: I think it may be related to the window manager - I'm running Xubuntu so my window manager is xfwm

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/42720450/120398 which describes how to make the focus follow the mouse cursor

Answer (score 6):

try to change following.

```
hw.keyboard = yes
hw.keyboard.lid = no
hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
```