# Host (Ubuntu 18.04) keyboard input not working on AVD after having run react-native app

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, react-native

I'm trying to get started with react-native and a virtual device in android studio on my Ubuntu 18.04 OS, following (as diligently as I have managed): https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html.

After running into several problems along the way (such as [Unable to load script from assets index.android.bundle on windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44446523/unable-to-load-script-from-assets-index-android-bundle-on-windows), using top voted fix) I'm now able to start an app using react-native run-android on a virtual device that I've created.

However after having started the react-native app I can no longer use any keyboard input from my desktop comp when on the virtual device, and e.g. opening dev options (ctrl+m) does no longer work. In fact a cold reboot of the device will not even do it, rather I need to reboot my computer (although that's probably a bit over the top) in order to get it working again.

"Enable keyboard input" in "Show advanced settings" of the AVD settings is set for the device and before I load the react-native host keyboard input into the virtual device works just fine.

Running react-native info yields:

```
React Native Environment Info:
    System:
      OS: Linux 4.15 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)
      CPU: x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3517U CPU @ 1.90GHz
      Memory: 240.89 MB / 7.67 GB
      Shell: 4.4.19 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 9.11.2 - /usr/bin/node
      npm: 6.3.0 - /usr/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    SDKs:
      Android SDK:
        Build Tools: 26.0.3, 28.0.1
        API Levels: 23, 26, 28
    npmPackages:
      react: 16.4.1 => 16.4.1 
      react-native: 0.56.0 => 0.56.0 
    npmGlobalPackages:
      create-react-native-app: 1.0.0
      react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Does anything look off to you?

I'm new to app development and am most grateful for any pointers on how to solve this!

/Adam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked when using fix:
[Android AVD keyboard input not working all the time on xUbuntu OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39993352/android-avd-keyboard-input-not-working-all-the-time-on-xubuntu-os/42720450#42720450)

I guess I should've mentioned I'm on Xubuntu, and not Ubuntu =)

/Adam